# Replacing a particular word in a text file : C++ , to a pre-defined value

Tags: c++, replace, file-handling

So I have a program to simulate how a **macro** works in a compliler.
The input program is take in a file : Say ***input.txt*** (Text file).

Supposed it had contents like this :

```
#include<iostream>
#define PI 3.14
```

What I want to do is, find the occurrence of the word PI after this and replace it with 3.14 in the file. I use FilePointer>>CharacterBuffer to read word by word from the file. How do I replace it in the file after doing all this?
Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just use the c-preprocessor to do this?!?

Comment: I think you have to output to a different file.

Comment: Can you please explain what 'string::npos' does here @ravi. Thank you for your quick answer. <br>

Comment: @Galik. I have succesfully done that. But I want to do it without having to create a new file, making changes there, renaming it after deleting the old file. :)

Comment: Then be prepared to do a lot of shifting and copying of characters from one part of the file to another. `tellg()`, `tellp()`, `seekg()` and `seekp()` are your only friends. ;o)

Comment: FWIW tools that do this kind of thing rarely modify the input file itself and if they do, they likely output to a separate temporary file first and overwrite the original file afterwards.

Comment: @WhatIfTheyGetMe: There's a good reason that writing a new file and then renaming is the most popular approach -- it doesn't destroy your data if the program aborts.

Comment: @Galik I did exactly that sir. And I have managed to accomplish it. But what I ask of you is a method to modify it directly in the file without using a buffer(temporary file). Maybe using read and write on the same time at the same time(ifstream and ofstream?)

Comment: @WhatIfTheyGetMe: Because your replacement text is longer than the original, you'll need to go forward through the file, counting replacements and calculating final size.  Then you'll need to go through backwards, copying unmodified text and replacement strings into their final locations in reverse order.  I suggest you read about the difference between `memcpy` and `memmove`, it's basically the same issue.

Comment: But just don't do it in-place.  Using a new file is far more robust.

Comment: Doing it *in place* is far less efficient and far more complicated. That's the bottom line.

Comment: Fair enough. I have now considered many method trying to replace it _inplace_ and none of them seem to end with fewer lines of code. Thank you all for your great advices and knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with following code for replacing a string in a file:-

```
    string line;
    size_t len = stringToReplace.length();          //replace is a string to be replaced.
    while (getline(in, line))
    {
        while (true)
        {
            size_t pos = line.find(stringToReplace);
            if (pos != string::npos)
                line.replace(pos, len, stringToReplace);
            else 
                break;
        }

        out << line << '\n';
    }
```

Comment: This will NOT work if `in` and `out` are both the same file, as they are in this question.